# Computing the Covariance of a Gaussian Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, covariance

Let $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ be independent centered Gaussian processes with covariance function $(s,t)\mapsto \min(s,t) - st$. I want to compute the variance of $$X:=\left(-\int_0^1\mathcal G(s)\,\mathrm ds + \int_0^1\mathcal H(s)\,\mathrm ds\right).$$

Since
\begin{align*}
X^2 &= \left(-\int_0^1\mathcal G(s)\,\mathrm ds + \int_0^1\mathcal H(s)\,\mathrm ds\right)\left(-\int_0^1\mathcal G(s)\,\mathrm ds + \int_0^1\mathcal H(s)\,\mathrm ds\right) \\
&= \int_0^1\int_0^1\mathcal G(s)\mathcal G(t)\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt + \int_0^1\int_0^1\mathcal H(s)\mathcal H(t)\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt - \int_0^1\int_0^1\mathcal G(s)\mathcal H(t)\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt - \int_0^1\int_0^1\mathcal H(s)\mathcal G(t)\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt.
\end{align*}
Using Fubini, I can interchange expectation and integration operations. Since the Gaussian processes are centered, I obtain $\operatorname E\mathcal G(s)\mathcal G(t) = \min(s,t) - st$, $\operatorname E\mathcal H(s)\mathcal H(t) = \min(s,t)-st$, $\operatorname E\mathcal H(s)\mathcal G(t) = 0$, and $\operatorname E\mathcal H(t)\mathcal G(s) = 0$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname EX^2 &= \int_0^1\int_0^1(\min(s,t)-st)\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt + \int_0^1\int_0^1(\min(s,t)-st)\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt - 0 \\
&= 2\int_0^1\left(\int_0^ts\,\mathrm ds + \int_t^1t\,\mathrm ds\right)\,\mathrm dt - 2\int_0^1\int_0^1st\,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm dt \\
&= \int_0^1 (2t-t^2)\,\mathrm dt - \frac 12 \\
&= \frac 2{12}.
\end{align*}
However, the solution is supposed to be $\frac 1{12}$. But I cannot spot my mistake....

Comment: To me it looks like $$
2\int_0^tt^2/2+t-t^2\,dt-2\int_0^1t/2\,dt=\int_0^1t-t^2\,dt=1/2-1/3=1/6.
$$

Comment: but this can't be true; I opened another question with more details why it can't be true. Maybe I made I mistake earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{equation*}
 \hat{F}_X^{(m)}=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\boldsymbol{1}_{X_i\le t}, \quad
 \hat{F}_X^{(n)}=n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\boldsymbol{1}_{Y_j\le t}.
\end{equation*}
In above, by Functional Delta Method, you derive that
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{n}[\phi(\hat{F}_X^{(n)},\hat{F}_Y^{(n)})-\phi(F_X,F_Y)]\\
 &\quad \stackrel{\text{in dist.}}{\longrightarrow} -\int_0^1\mathcal{H}\,\mathrm{d}F_X+\int_0^1\mathcal{G}\,\mathrm{d}F_Y \stackrel{d}{=} N(0,\tfrac16).  
\end{align*}
This fact consist also with the (40) and (42) in the notes you mentioned. It suffice
notice that, here $N=2n$ and $n=n_1=n_2$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{N}(U-1/2)\approx N(0,N^2/(12n^2)),\quad \sqrt{n} (U-1/2)\approx N(0,1/6)).
\end{equation*}

Comment: oh my gosh... my mistake was to take $N = n$ instead of $N = 2n$. Thank you very much!

Comment: (feel free to also post the answer in my other question)