# Computing the Variance of a Gaussian Random Variable (follow-up question)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

This is a follow-up question on [Computing the Covariance of a Gaussian Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678503/computing-the-covariance-of-a-gaussian-process). The user @Kurt G. confirmed my result there, but there must be a mistake in my computations. Therefore, I want to share the full question with more details as there must be a mistake apparently somewhere else.

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ and $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_n$ are iid random variables from continuous probability distributions $F_X$ and $F_Y$, respectively. Both $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are assumed to have support on $[0,1]$. Let $$\hat F_X(t) = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf 1_{(-\infty..t]}(X_i)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \hat F_Y(t) = n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf 1_{(-\infty..t]}(Y_i)$$ for $t\in\mathbb R$. By Donsker's Theorem, the vector
$$\sqrt n\begin{pmatrix}
\hat F_X - F_X \\ \hat F_Y - F_Y
\end{pmatrix}$$
converges in distribution to two independent centered Gaussian processes $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal H$ on $[0,1]$ with variance-covariance function $(t,s)\mapsto F_X(\min(s,t)) - F_X(s)F_Y(t)$ and $(t,s)\mapsto F_Y(\min(s,t)) - F_X(s)F_Y(t)$, respectively. Now consider the bounded bilinear form $\phi$ given by $$\phi(A,B) = \int_0^1 A\,\mathrm dB$$ on the Banach space of real-valued functions that are of bounded variation. This bilinear form is Hadamard differentiable at $(F_X,F_Y)$ with Hadamard derivative $$\phi'(A,B) = B(F_Y(1)) - B(F_X(0)) - \int_0^1 B\,\mathrm dF_X + \int_0^1 A\,\mathrm dF_Y.$$ By the [Functional Delta Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#Nonparametric_delta_method), $$\sqrt n\Big(\phi(\hat F_X, \hat F_Y) -  \phi(F_X,F_Y)\Big)$$ converges in distribution to $$\phi'(\mathcal G, \mathcal H) = \mathcal H(1) - \mathcal H(0) - \int_0^1\mathcal H\,\mathrm dF_X + \int_0^1\mathcal G\,\mathrm dF_Y = - \int_0^1\mathcal H\,\mathrm dF_X + \int_0^1\mathcal G\,\mathrm dF_Y.$$
Clearly, $\phi'(\mathcal G, \mathcal H)$ is normally distributed with mean zero. The variance should be given by $\operatorname E[\phi'(\mathcal G, \mathcal H)^2]$. I computed the variance explicitly here [Computing the Covariance of a Gaussian Process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678503/computing-the-covariance-of-a-gaussian-process) (note that $F_X$ and $F_Y$ were assumed to be the identity there for simplicity). The answer appears to be $\frac 16$. But this can't be true as $\phi(\hat F_X, \hat F_Y)$ is just the Mann-Whitney test statistic which is known to have an asymptotic variance of $\frac 1{12}$ (see, e.g., [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Stat200C/Ustat.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etom/Stat200C/Ustat.pdf) Equation 42). However, I can't see where my reasoning is wrong or where I made a mistake.

Comment: pls refer the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4678503/computing-the-covariance-of-a-gaussian-process/)